Fraunhofer diffraction from composite apertures
I'm trying to calculate the fraunhofer diffraction pattern from a aperture composed of multiple simple shapes, but I've ran into  some trouble when trying to simulate the results and I really dont know if my derivation of the pattern is wrong or if my code is simply acting up.
The aperture is simply a rectangle with some arbitrary width W1 and height H1, centered in the aperture plane, and two more rectangles with some arbitrary width W2 and height H2 on each side of the central rectangle. So the composite shape could be an H, or a plus sign, or some other shape, it doesnt really matter. As far as I can tell, the fraunhofer diffraction patter should simply be proportional to the Fourier transform of the aperture function, evaluated at $(k_x,k_y) = (\frac{x}{\lambda z},\frac{y}{\lambda z})$. In this case then, the aperture function $f(x,y)$ is "simply"
$$f(x,y) = rect(\frac{x}{W1})rect(\frac{y}{H1})+rect(\frac{x-\frac{W1+W2}{2}}{W2})rect(\frac{y}{H2})+rect(\frac{x+\frac{W1+W2}{2}}{W2})rect(\frac{y}{H2})$$
and the Fourier transform is
$$F(k_x,k_y) = W1 \cdot H1 \cdot sinc(W1 k_x)sinc(H1 k_y) + \exp(-i k_x \frac{W1+W2}{W1})\cdot  W1 \cdot H1 \cdot sinc(W1 k_x)sinc(H1 k_y) + \exp(i k_x \frac{W1+W2}{W2}) \cdot W2 \cdot H2 \cdot sinc(W2 k_x)sinc(H2 k_y)  $$
My question is, is this allowed? To define the aperture piecewise in the way above, and then use the fourier shift theorem to obtain the diffraction pattern as the sum of phase shifted sinc functions. Im asking because when I implement it in python, the pattern differs from the pattern I obtain using a DFT of the same aperture. Appreciate any input, I'm at my wits end.

Hi, did you ever figure out how to modify the off-center parts of your aperture function to get the results to agree?
I think the approach of describing the aperture as a composite of positive and negative apertures only works when all contributing parts are on-axis. When you have an asymmetric aperture, the corresponding off-axis apertures need to be modified because this approach implies taking the Fourier transforms wrt to the center of each individual part. So breaking up the Fourier transform in the individual parts only works when their centers coincide.

After some thought, this is probably an issue of resolution. The phases acquired due to the shifts of the apertures are small and the plane of the DFT (eg. some fft algorithm) might not be the same you get when manually computing the Fourier transforms. So overall, you probably had no major problem.

Also, check again your Fourier transforms, your exponential functions have dimensional arguments (1/length) - which can't be correct. Use the properties of the Fourier transform to get the correct result.
